# How could i use custom manager of the related model, when using select_related?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-managers

For example, I have models as,

```
class ModelBManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.super().get_queryset().select_related('y')

class ModelA(models.Model):
    x = models.TextField()

class ModelB(models.Model):
    y = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)
    objects = ModelBManager()

class ModelC(models.Model):
    z = models.ForeignKey(ModelB)
```

Now, if i do `ModelC.objects.get(id=1).z` i would get the `ModelB` instance with a prefetched `ModelA` instance( `ModelBManager` worked).

But if i do `ModelC.objects.select_related('z')[0].z`, there would be no prefetched `ModelA` instance with `ModelB` instance.(Basically `ModelBManager` did not work!)

Anyone has any idea how can i achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`select_related` allows using spans fetch deeper relationships.

In you case you should use `ModelC.objects.select_related('z__y').first().z.y`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me! Docs from your link states: _Base managers aren’t used when querying on related models._ Ideas?

Comment: If your case is similar to the one in the question you can just `ModelC.objects.select_related('z__y').first().z.y`

Comment: No, it's not that simple for me. In my custom manager I add multiple annotations to original queryset. Now, I want to keep those annotations through select_related() by foreign model... Don't want to add annotations over there again (DRY)...